# How to track xml, which is sent to the server

Tags: java, web-services

I'm new in web-services and i have a problem.
On my local machine i run application.
My steps:
  add axis libs, generate code through eclipse(with wsdl file). Set some values and Run.
Result:
  deserialization error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
I think that some values are not setted in xml file. So i want to track how this xml look, when i sent it to the server.
I try make it through soapUI, but here i can only generate xml file and sent him(And when i didn't set some values - i did get the same Exception). But i want to see how looks this xml file generated by java code.
Any idea's?
P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) might be helpful to you - it logs HTTP traffic. To start off, [take a look at the video demos](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/video/).

Comment: Thank you, it's help, but instead of a structure xml I was expecting full valid xml. But here is no problem, as i think - troubles in generated xml.